# how to find percentage or area of overlapped area of a polygon

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, spatial

In SQL Server 2008 R2 I have created some polygons. I have also selected which polygon is overlapping another one  Now I want to know overlapped area or percentage.

For area I am trying following SQL

```
SELECT location.STArea()
FROM
  ( SELECT location.STIntersection(
           (SELECT LOCATION
            FROM TEST.dbo.cn_overlap_trn
            WHERE plot_no = '657065700016801' ) )
   FROM TEST.dbo.cn_overlap_trn
   WHERE plot_no ='657065700016701') ;
```

in above SQL

```
SELECT location.STIntersection(
       (SELECT LOCATION
        FROM TEST.dbo.cn_overlap_trn
        WHERE plot_no = '657065700016801' ) )
FROM TEST.dbo.cn_overlap_trn
WHERE plot_no ='657065700016701';
```

is running fine but when I add `STArea()` function it results an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Answer (score 1):

You need an Alias for your subquery say `A` and also to your functions specially in your inner query  for example:

```
Select location.STArea() as Area from
(
    select 
    location.STIntersection(
        ( 
        select location from TEST.dbo.cn_overlap_trn where plot_no =  '657065700016801'
        )
                            ) as Intersection
    from TEST.dbo.cn_overlap_trn 
    where plot_no ='657065700016701'
) A ;
```

Comment: Error ===>  **Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 11
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'area'.**

Comment: @Ravi include aliases for your functions also. Check my update above.